# Wordpress: frontpage returns 500, all other content work

Tags: wordpress

I can't seem to find what is causing a sudden issue with this customer website, powered by wordpress. All links work and load fast except for the frontpage, which seem to load for 1 minute then eventually ends with being redirected to http://www.domain.com/500.phtml

I've tried:

- disabling all plugins, the problem remains.
- changing .htaccess permissions, to 644, then 666, no go.

I'm a bit confused as to what other steps would make sense. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is hard to diagnose without seeing the site files. I would check the wp-config.php to make sure that it wasn't corrupted or missing elements that it was supposed to have (secret keys and so forth). If you recently did an upgrade to WP 3.4 + your host needs to be running PHP 5.2.4 or better. The previous version 3.3 (I think or perhaps 3.2) required a lesser PHP version. If your host isn't PHP 5.2.4, you might get that error.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/internal-error-500-501

Comment: Nope, the blog is running fine, other than the frontpage.

Comment: ok the only difference from a front page and the rest of the blog would be the main page template file for the front page. i would check that for any errors or bad calls or if it even exists. there must be something on that page that is causing the 500.

Comment: good points. I've looked at the front-page.php template: not much going on there. The Settings>Reading state that the frontpage should display 10 latest posts (excerpts). i renamed the template so it wouldn't be called. Problem still occurs. But if i change the settings to use a specific page (like my "contact" page) then it works.

Comment: you  were right: the error is caused by the function `get_sidebar();`. I did try a widget before the error occured. Now, at least i know where to look, thank you.

Comment: Set define('WP_DEBUG', true); on your wp-config.php file and you'll know for sure.